# IE (bug) percentages with background-position

Tags: css, internet-explorer, background-position

I'm having an issue in IE only with a background image for an element in a flexible/fluid layout.

Basically, I need the background image (which is 1px by 1px) to tile vertically. When the layout is at full width, the background image sits at **676px** from the left which when converted to percentages equals **70.56367%** (`676px divide by it's container of 958px`).

This **works fine** in **Firefox**, **Chrome** and **Safari** however **does not work in** any of the **IE**'s (6,7 and 8). The background position only seems to work when the percentage is a full number and not a fraction ie. Background position changes when set to 70% or 71% and so on.

Here is what I have and how it appears in the browsers:

```
background:url(link/to/image.gif) repeat-y 70.6680584551148% 0;/*676px/958px*/
```

I also tried setting the background position as separate X and Y values (same result though):

```
background-position-x:70.6680584551148%;/*676px/958px*/
background-position-y: 0;
```

**Firefox** (v3.6.3):

[image]

**Chrome** (12.0.742.100):

[image]

**Safari** (5.0.2):

[image]

**Internet Explorer** (6, 7 and 8 - all the same result):

[image]

So **my question is**, is this just an IE problem where the browser can not calculate a percentage that is not whole? Or, is there a fix or something I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was recently fiddling around with making a scalable site design based on percentage widths using `em`. Luckily for me, it was only prototyping because as it turned out, it seems IE ignores anything after the second decimal place. You can see for yourself by loading IE8 and hitting F12 to pull up the development console. Find your CSS with the percentage and see what it says.

Just for the record, my `em` measurements would have been like this `0.7056367` instead of this `70.56367%` which (in my tests) would have become `0.70`. It seems very feasible to me, then, that IE is rounding to the nearest percentage point (`70%`) or the nearest hundredth of a percent (`70.56%`) at most.

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to be the case. IE looks as though it is rounding the percentage to the nearest whole number. Even though it is saying 70.56% in IE's developer console, it doesn't seem to be applying the .56%, rather it's just applying the 70%.

Comment: @Dan: Yeah. As far as fixing it goes, perhaps you can use `70%` instead, that comes out to `670.6px` from `958px`. You might have better luck with the way that each browser handles a half pixel rather than a decimal percentage.

Comment: I wish it were that simple - unfortunately the widths are pretty exact. All good though, I'm going to have a quick look into http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-multi-column-liquid-layouts as a possible new way to laying the site out. Thanks for your feedback. I wait a few more hours to see if anyone else has feedback/solution. If nothing comes up, I'll be more then happy to mark your answer as correct. Cheers =)

Answer (score 0):

IE always make us doing more works.
maybe using different css style is the answer

```
<!--[if gte IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="iespecific.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Already have one @Zia. A separate stylesheet isn't the answer - this has to do with the browser rendering a width based on percentages. And the lack of IE ability when the percentage is not whole.

Comment: hmm, I see. sorry, i had different comprehension with your question

Answer (score 0):

The background image should fit the width of the container DIV, so your code should look like this:

```
background:url(link/to/image.gif) scroll repeat-y 0 0;
```

Comment: It's a flexible/fluid layout. When the browser window is reduced the background image has to move in toe to be the same width as the container it is acting as a divider for. So making the background image the same width as the container will not fix the problem because as soon as the user reduces the browser width, the image will no longer align.